# How to send model data as parameter in MVC3?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to pass model data as a parameter in my MVC 3 application. i write the follwoing code to achive the functionality

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         var modelData = <%= Model.ToJson() %>;
     });

 </script>
```

also write a JsonExtensions.cs class to extend the method. here I am getting **"expression expected"** error before the <% sign and getting following error when i run the application

**"Microsoft JScript runtime error: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101."**

I am not sure what i am missing here

Comment: Please show us the generated source.

Comment: This is inside a partial view so it doesn't generate any source